# Is it possible to apply padding directly in a Xamarin grid layout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The application I am working on has placed stack elements inside the grids and applied padding to them:

```
<Grid x:Name="detailGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Label x:Name="detail1" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
   </StackLayout>
   <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Label x:Name="detail2" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
   </StackLayout>
   <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Label x:Name="detail3" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
   </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Is it possible to eliminate the Stacklayout and apply this to the labels themselves?

Comment: As an additional optimization, you could also get rid of the `ColumnDefinitions` part. Since there's only 1 column it will automatically grab the full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code I removed all unnecessary code in this.

```
<Grid x:Name="detailGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,0" >
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Label x:Name="detail1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" /> 
      <Label x:Name="detail2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
      <Label x:Name="detail3" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are properties such as `RowSpacing` and `ColumnSpacing`.

In your case you want to apply margin to the left and right correct? So that would be 
`<Grid ColumnSpacing="10">`